# Mysql - 3 Seperate Sums from 1 Table - Works - Searching for a better Query

Tags: mysql, sql

**Story**: I have a single mysql table and I get 3 values (sums) wtih the query below. Query is working. But it takes  7.624 seconds and it is too long for me. Just trying to find a better sql query. Can you help me?

```
SELECT
    DATE(a.tarih),
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(s.stoplam)
        FROM
            siparis s
        WHERE
            s.durum_id IN (4, 26, 27, 28, 29)
        AND DATE(s.tarih) = DATE(a.tarih)
    ) AS iptal,
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(c.stoplam)
        FROM
            siparis c
        WHERE
            c.durum_id NOT IN (4, 26, 27, 28, 29)
        AND DATE(c.tarih) = DATE(a.tarih)
    ) AS Ciro,
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(d.stoplam)
        FROM
            siparis d
        WHERE
            d.durum_id NOT IN (4, 26, 27, 28, 29)

        AND DATE(d.tarih) = DATE_ADD(
            DATE(a.tarih),
            INTERVAL - 30 DAY
        )
    ) AS GCiro
FROM
    siparis a
WHERE
    DATE(a.tarih) > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 30 DAY)
GROUP BY
    DATE(a.tarih)
```

Comment: Is your a alias an orphan or am I blind?

Comment: @Mihai It doesn't seem to be the full query

Comment: Sorry. Now it should be a full query. Edited.

Comment: Another method is `UNION.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this much more easily with conditional aggregation, except for the third sum:

```
SELECT DATE(a.tarih),
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.durum_id IN (4, 26, 27, 28, 29) THEN s.stoplam ELSE 0 END) as iptal,
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.durum_id NOT IN (4, 26, 27, 28, 29) THEN s.stoplam ELSE 0 END) as Ciro,
       (SELECT SUM(d.stoplam)
        FROM siparis d
        WHERE d.durum_id NOT IN (4, 26, 27, 28, 29) AND
              DATE(d.tarih) = DATE_ADD(DATE(a.tarih), INTERVAL - 30 DAY)
       ) AS GCiro
FROM siparis a
WHERE DATE(a.tarih) > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 30 DAY)
GROUP BY DATE(a.tarih);
```

Comment: Thank you!. It was taking 8 sec and now 0.3 sec :).